# Django creating new project - access is denied

Tags: python, django, cmd

I'm trying to create a Django project with the command:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

unfortunately, I get the error:

```
CommandError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C\\Windows\\mysite'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: maybe try running the django-admin command in a different directory where you have write-access?

Answer (score 1):

Start the project in a different directory, for example in your home directory.

You likely don't have permission to create a subdirectory there, nor would you want to create a Django project under `C:\Windows`.

Comment: I agree with this. I don't see the reason why you would want to add a Django project in your `C:\Windows` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command as administrator. 
In start menu right click on cmd and click on `Run As Administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, resolved it with including the `-name` flag

```
django-admin startproject -name mysite
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happen because of software like CROWDSTRIKE.
Easy way is to create a virtual environment by running cmd as administrator:

then,if using **pycharm**:

1. click file
2. click settings
3. change python interpreter to your manually created virual environment

i hope this works for you, cause it did for me.